# Datatype Error in submission

Tags: vb.net

I have this huge problem with my vb.net code. Everything seem fine and i cant quite figure out where the problem is. I want to submit a record to an Access database but i get this datatype mismatch error everytime. My access database is all text for the fields. except for the dates which have datatype DATE.

```
    Try
        'LGCodeHygNumb()
        Dim statement As String
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
        Dim connect As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Persist Security Info=false; Data Source=..\ClosedIn11.mdb")
        'If connect.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        connect.Open()
        'End If

        statement = "INSERT INTO EnrolleeDets (ID, Surname, FirstName, Othername, ReceiptNumber, Birthdate, Gender, MaritalStatus, HomeAddress, Mobile, Telephone, State, StateCode, Local_Govt, GroupType, GroupName, Location, ElectiveType, Provider, PassportDirectory, Original_RegDate, New_RenewalDate, ExpiryDate, Status, OverallStatus) values ('" & lblnumb.Text & "', '" & txtSurnanme.Text & "', '" & txtFirstname.Text & "', '" & txtNickname.Text & "', '" & txtReceiptNo.Text & "', '" & DatePicker1.Text & "', '" & cmbGender.Text & "', '" & cmbMaritalStatus.Text & "', '" & txtHomeAddr.Text & "', '" & txtMobile.Text & "', '" & TextBox8.Text & "', '" & cmbState.Text & "', '" & cmbStateCode.Text & "', '" & cmbLGACode.Text & "', '" & cmbGroupType.Text & "', '" & cmbGroupName.Text & "', '" & cmbLocation.Text & "', '" & cmbElectiveType.Text & "', '" & cmbProvider.Text & "', '" & txtPassportDir.Text & "','" & txtPassportDir.Text & "', '" & txtPassportDir.Text & "', '" & txtPassportDir.Text & "', '" & txtPassportDir.Text & "', '" & txtPassportDir.Text & "')"
        'MsgBox(statement)
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(statement, connect)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        'MsgBox(lblnumb.Text & " added under " & txtSurnanme.Text & " !", vbInformation)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
    'connect.Close()
```

Comment: This link will fix your current (and future) problems: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please beware of SQL Injection using inline SQL. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Thanks Roger. I guess i forgot to add that i am a newbie in vb.net programming. Having scrutinised the code over and over i dont seem to find anything wrong with the composition. Except that i keep getting datatype mismatch everytime i attempt to submit to database.

Comment: @Joseph If you think you've fixed your problem, please enter `O'Hare` in the `txtSurnanme` textbox and run your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your statement:

```
statement = "INSERT INTO EnrolleeDets (ID, Surname, FirstName, Othername, ReceiptNumber, Birthdate, Gender, MaritalStatus, HomeAddress, Mobile, Telephone, State, StateCode, Local_Govt, GroupType, GroupName, Location, ElectiveType, Provider, PassportDirectory, Original_RegDate, New_RenewalDate, ExpiryDate, Status, OverallStatus) values ('" & lblnumb.Text & "', '" & txtSurnanme.Text & "', '" & txtFirstname.Text & "', '" & txtNickname.Text & "', '" & txtReceiptNo.Text & "', '" & DatePicker1.Text & "', '" & cmbGender.Text & "', '" & cmbMaritalStatus.Text & "', '" & txtHomeAddr.Text & "', '" & txtMobile.Text & "', '" & TextBox8.Text & "', '" & cmbState.Text & "', '" & cmbStateCode.Text & "', '" & cmbLGACode.Text & "', '" & cmbGroupType.Text & "', '" & cmbGroupName.Text & "', '" & cmbLocation.Text & "', '" & cmbElectiveType.Text & "', '" & cmbProvider.Text & "', '" & txtPassportDir.Text & "','" & txtPassportDir.Text & "', '" & txtPassportDir.Text & "', '" & txtPassportDir.Text & "', '" & txtPassportDir.Text & "', '" & txtPassportDir.Text & "')"
```

Your columns `Original_RegDate, New_RenewalDate, ExpiryDate` match up with `'" & txtPassportDir.Text & "', '" & txtPassportDir.Text & "', '" & txtPassportDir.Text & "'`

I would guess that txtPassportDir.Text does not contain a date.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the command using [OleDbParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
statement = "INSERT INTO EnrolleeDets (Surname, Birthdate, Status) values (@ID, @Birthdate, @Status);"
```

Make sure that the added values have correct data type:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", Me.TextBox1.Text) ' VarChar
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Birthdate", Date.Parse(Me.TextBox2.Text)) 'DateTime
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", Integer.Parse(Me.TextBox3.Text)) 'Int
```